# Banner not displaying correctly

Tags: media

I have uploaded a banner onto my site, and it is not displaying correctly; yet, the content type it appears correctly in my browser.

It appears as though the black areas are not rendering correctly, as shown in the image below.

[image: screenshot][image: screenshot]

I have tried both .GIF and .JPEG.

This is the first time it has happened with over 100 banners, and I have even used this same image before.

This image shows the GIF settings.

[image: screenshot]

It seems to be an issue with the scale and crop functionality of Drupal image toolkit, where the transparency of the image gets changed.

Comment: In the GIF image, did you set transparent color to black and save the image with the transparent color by mistake ? Are you sure the same issue with jpeg image ? Did you clear your cache before trying jpeg ?

Comment: No, Yes and Yes, :)

Comment: what about color depth in your image, ie how is this encoded? any special encoding? how many bits per pixel ?